# Помогите со знаками препинания, включая тире

Tags: пунктуация

Самое главное, что она стала мне другом и ни разу не подвела.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы правильно расставили все знаки препинания!

Запятая перед *и* не нужна, потому что этот союз стоит между одноподными сказуемыми.

Вообще, можно поставить авторское тире перед «и ни разу не подвела», но я бы не стал этого делать — всё и так хорошо :)

Answer (score 1):

**Самое главное, что она стала мне другом и ни разу не подвела.**

Знаки препинания расставлены верно, но нужно еще правильно определить грамматику предложения.

Это простое предложения с однородными сказуемыми, связанными союзом И. Запятой выделено вводное сочетание "самое главное".